# Best solution for dynamic home page layout

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I'm doing a site of news with Symfony2. At home page, I need to dynamize the disposition of the boxes. I made two examples of model.

In the first model I'll have 10 boxes, each one with your thematic (sports, last news, most read, etc):

[image: First model]

In the second model I'll have 8 boxes (with differents thematics, or not):

[image: Second mode]

So, I'll have several models: what's the best way to store this models and your thematics? In the database or another way? Can someone help me?

PS: I guess others questions like this were treated as subjective, but I'm looking for best performance because I'll have thousand of accesses.

UPDATE

Sorry, I forgot important points:

- I have two tables that certainly I will use: news and tags;
- The website administrator will set the actual model, something like "Manage home page" > "Choose model" > "Set a thematic for each box";
- In the last step of this "management", the administrator will can choose a tag or a news to associate to the box (when the 'superadmin' add a model he says whether is a box of news or tags).

Comment: I think you need to use `if elseif else` statement, checking some variable, for example `$type`, and with any type display any layout code or better include different templates

Comment: I think you need to use `javascript`

Comment: How many layouts will you have at the end? Will you allow users to make their own layouts?

Comment: @n.1, I know my jounalists, in 2 years I will have more then 20 layouts... no, I will create the models.

Comment: How do you decide which one layout is served? Is it an user choice or your choice?

Comment: @n.1 sorry! i've updated the question...

Answer (score 2):

I think that you must use two different twig templates that you manage from your controller.

And, maybe that Twitter Bootstrap can help you to build your templates easily.

Comment: ok, but where should I store the info that says the theme? can you show how would stay the database relations?

Answer (score 1):

This kind of post should be posted in ux.se or programmers.se, anyway...

Save your thematics on your database. On a different table, connect both table via IDs (fk/pk).

On your model, those extra info, properties, its thematics should be loaded along then your controller or in your 'middle-man-model' should generate proper html with ids and classes.

Then all those styles are done through css.

Now for a more control over the design, fluidity, flexibility and consistency of your page, use javascript or jquery, where CSS alone could not do.